# Angular/bootstrap collapse button collapsing all elements

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Bootstrap, Angular and Django, so I'll try my best to be as clear as possible. I have several dynamic generated div's by a django loop, and for each div a collapse button. I set the data-target of each button to a dynamically attributed id for each element (I use a django variable that is being pulled in the loop for it), but regardless of what button I press all the div's will be collapsed/uncollapsed.

```
{% for country in countries %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="country-panel col-xs-12" style="background:url({{ country.country_image}}) no-repeat; position: relative;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="country-name col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <p class="title">{{ country.name | upper }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="description-panel col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="content">{{ country.content }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    {% for city in country.cities %}
                        {% if forloop.counter <= 3 %}
                            {% if forloop.counter < 3 %}
                                <a><div class="col-xs-4 city-block right" style="background:url({{city.image}}) no-repeat; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
                            {% elif forloop.counter == 3 %}
                                <a><div class="col-xs-4 city-block" style="background:url({{city.image}}) no-repeat; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
                            {% endif %}
                                    <div class="city-layer"></div>
                                    <span class="city-name">{{city.name | upper}}</span>
                                </div></a>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>  
                    <div class="row" uib-collapse="isCollapsed" id="{{country.name}}">
                        {% for city in country.cities %}
                            {% if forloop.counter > 3 %}
                                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                                <a><div class="col-xs-4 city-block" style="background:url({{city.image}}) no-repeat; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
                                {% else %}
                                <a><div class="col-xs-4 city-block right" style="background:url({{city.image}}) no-repeat; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
                                {% endif %}
                                    <div class="city-layer"></div>
                                    <span class="city-name">{{city.name | upper}}</span>
                                </div></a>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <p class="content">{{country.description}}</p>
                            <p><div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-10"><a class="btn-default pink-button more-cities col-xs-12" role="button" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" data-target="#{{country.name}}">{% trans "MORE CITIES" %}&nbsp<span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></div></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-separator col-xs-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Please not that I've started web development a month or 2 ago and also First time posting on stackoverflow, so please be gentle.

Comment: Would be great if you could create a jsfiddle

Comment: I'll try my best, but not sure how it will turn out, since libraries are being pulled by require.js, and some of django/python is mixed with the html
EDIT: Can't put it on jsfiddle, ty for trying to help anyway :)

Comment: It should be possible to put on jsfiddle, you don't need to include the django side of things on there (I dont think its a django issue) just start with a couple of django rendered html elements and then add any other functionality (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I forgot to pass the ng-controller in the collapse div, for the controller that has my collapse functions. Thank you for all the help anyway!